# Wordpress plugin with 3rd party jquery plugin integration

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

Can I use third party jquery plugins in my wordpress plugin? Can't find anything about this. What would the structure look like? Would I enqueue the script like I'm working in a theme? I'm pretty new to wordpress.

Also does my plugin need a doctype and a head tag and all of that? I'm guessing not?

I'm trying to take a non-wordpress script and turn it into a plugin. Here's my code, I'm using this 3rd party plugin - http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

```
<?php
```

/*

Plugin Name: Crashboard

Description: a crash test

Version: 0.3

Author: Fuzzy Logic

License: GPL2

*/

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CrashBoard</title>
<link href="css/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://filamentgroup.github.com/EnhanceJS/enhance.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/visualize.jQuery.js'></script>
<link href='css/visualize.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />     
<link href='css/visualize-light.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<style>
#chart{
    display: none;
}

#chart7{
    display: none;
}

#gross{
    display: none;
}

#gross7{
    display: none;
}

#table_2 {
margin-left: 550px;
margin-top: -668px;
margin-bottom: 474px;
}

#sevenchart {
margin-left: 520px;
margin-top: -450px;
}

#sevengross{
margin-left: 260px;
margin-top: -30px;
}

#thirtychart {
margin-top: -38px;
margin-left: 22px;
}

#thirtygross {
margin-top: -38px;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#chart thead, td{
min-width: 60px;
}
</style>            
<script type="text/javascript">            
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#table').visualize({type: 'area', width: 950, height: 270}).appendTo('#thirtychart');

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<table id="table">
<caption>30 Day Sales Overview</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">Units Sold</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Value Sold</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Clicks from Referrals</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Referrals to Sales</th>
        <th scope="col">Total commission Paid Out</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php

        global $wpdb;

        $y='';

        for($i=30; $i>=0; $i--){

            $the_time = time() - ($i * 24 * 60 * 60);

            $the_date = date('m-d', $the_time);

            echo "<th scope=\"row\">" . $the_date . "</th>";

            $day_quant = '';

            $day_gross = '';

            $day_clicks = '';

            $day_completes = '';

            $day_payments = '';

            $iminus1 = '';

            $iminus1 = $i-1;

            $ipn_list = $wpdb->get_results("Select * FROM paypal_ipn WHERE paypal_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $i day) AND paypal_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $iminus1 day)");

            if($ipn_list!=null){

                foreach( $ipn_list as $ipn_data ){

                    $order_quant = $ipn_data->quantity;

                    $day_quant += $order_quant; 

                    $order_gross = $ipn_data->payment_gross;

                    $day_gross += $order_gross; 

                }

                echo "<td>" . $day_quant . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $day_gross . "</td>";  


            }else{

                echo "<td>0</td>"; 
                echo "<td>0</td>";  

            }

            $affiliate_list = $wpdb->get_results("Select * FROM wp_affiliatedata WHERE paypal_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $i day) AND paypal_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $iminus1 day)");

            if($affiliate_list!=null){

                foreach( $affiliate_list as $affiliate_data ){

                    $refer_clicks = $affiliate_data->uniques;

                    $day_clicks += $refer_clicks;   

                    $refer_completes = $affiliate_data->completes;

                    $day_completes += $refer_completes; 

                    $refer_payments = $affiliate_data->payments;

                    $day_payments += $refer_payments;   

                }               

                echo "<td>" . $day_clicks . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  $day_completes . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  $day_payments . "</td>";   

            }else{

                echo "<td>0</td>";
                echo "<td>0</td>";
                echo "<td>0</td>"; 
                echo "</tr>";   

            }


            }
        ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make this a dashboard widget, so from what I've seen, I need to put the main script into 1 function and register the function..but how would third party jquery and css fit into that, if at all? Thanks so much for the help in advance!

Comment: As for me the easiest way to know can you do something or not is to try to do it

Comment: My experience with wordpress, not being a wordpress developer, is that it won't work, unless I know the secret wordpress way to do it, so that's what I'm asking about..enqueueing scripts is a great example..tried forever to get the non-wordpress fancybox to work, and didn't get it until I discovered wordpress' enqueue_script feature..looking for maybe something like that here..when I search jquery and wordpress plugin I get all kinds of irrelevant stuff for my question

Comment: at first glance, this seems like it will help..http://www.jdmweb.com/resources/jquery_to_wordpress_plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing article, found everything I was looking for - http://www.jdmweb.com/resources/jquery_to_wordpress_plugin

Here's the code I needed with Fancybox as the example 3rd-party jquery plugin:

```
//Group the code inside a function
function fancybox_wp_setup(){
  wp_enqueue_style(
  "jquery.fancybox", WP_PLUGIN_URL."/jQuery2Wp_fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css", 
  false, "1.3.1");

  wp_enqueue_script("jquery");

  wp_enqueue_script(
  "jquery.fancybox", WP_PLUGIN_URL."/jQuery2Wp_fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js", 
  array("jquery"), "1.3.1",1);  

  wp_enqueue_script(
  "jquery.fancyboxsetup", WP_PLUGIN_URL."/jQuery2Wp_fancybox/fancybox-setup.js", 
  array("jquery","jquery.fancybox"), "",1);
}
```